# How to retrieve parameters in a Zend layout

Tags: zend-framework, layout, parameter-passing

I'm working through the book "Zend Framework - A beginners guide".
Part of the third chapter describes working with a masterlayout.

For my navigation I'd like to set the id-attrib of the body dynamically. How can I get a parameter from any controller to this layout-file?

The master-layout is set in application.ini:

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts"
resources.layout.layout = master
```

greetings
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use view vars for simple variables you need to pass into layout scripts:

**In your controller:**

```
function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->pageTitle = "Zend Layout Example";
}
```

**In your layout script:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $this->escape($this->pageTitle); ?></title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this, is to use placeholders.  Here's an example layout:

```
master.phtml
------------
<html>
   <head>
      <title>My Master Layout</title>
   </head>
   <body id="<?= $this->placeholder('my_dynamic_id_attrib'); ?>">
    ...
   </body>
</html>
```

Note that the value for the "id" attribute starts with "`<?=`".  This is the same as "`<?php echo`" and it should work correctly if you're using the default .htaccess file which Zend recommends.  If "`<?=`" does not work for you, simply replace it with:

```
<body id="<?php echo $this->placeholder('my_dynamic_id_attrib'); ?>">
```

Now, in your controller, you can set your dynamic id using:

```
IndexController.php
-------------------
public function indexAction(){

  //------------------------------------
  // Can either be $_GET or $_POST, etc.
  $dynamicParam = $this->_getParam('id');

  //------------------------------------
  // Set the dynamic id
  $this->view->placeholder('my_dynamic_id_attrib')->set($dynamicParam);
}
```

Comment: Anytime Frankie. Thanks for posting your question. Best